# rtph264pay sequence numbering

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtp

I have a question regarding the rtph264pay element and the udpsink element. In the rtph264pay element, we use a for loop to iterate over the frame and break it down into 1400-byte size (MTU) packets and we append them to a linked list.

I want to see if I can potentially parallelize this operation and shave off a few ms in this process. The question is, do we do any kind of application-layer RTP specific sequence numbering in the rtph264pay element? It appears that we dont. We just add these MTUs to a linked list in order. So where do we add any kind of sequence numbering information?

Answer (score 0):

> do any kind of application-layer RTP specific sequence numbering in the rtph264pay element?

No - its done in rtp base payload class for all rtp implementations.
Remember gstreamer uses C stylish inheritance

> So where do we add any kind of sequence numbering information?

[Here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst-libs/gst/rtp/gstrtpbasepayload.c#n1144)

HTH